# Merge object at vertex

Tags: objects

I have been trying to look this up for a tutorial for the better part of a week, and I've had no manner of luck.

I have two objects - both "cubes" of different dimensions, and I would like to merge them together. One is 4x4x20, the other is 1x20x5. I wish to align a single corner vertex of each object, as if I were bolting a length-wise piece of wood to an upright (which is what I'm trying to model), merging them without having to stretch any individual faces of either object. The entire object will have to move (either one), and I am at a total loss of how to make this happen. Please, someone, tell me what I'm missing.

Simplified screenshot of my desired ending point:
[image]

It's not perfect, because I can't get it to be perfect.

Comment: Select both and press `Ctrl`+`J` to join?

Comment: Please post a screen shot of the items and the desired end positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Select one of the objects in object mode, change the *snap element* option from increment to vertex,

[image]

Press G, hold Ctrl, and move the mouse to the vertex of the other object you want the first object to align to.

[image]

Comment: Even when I set it to snap to vertex, it doesn't snap - it stays just where I put it, which is not (quite) where it needs to be.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get it to snap to a vertex - but it's the wrong one. How do I choose which vertex to snap to, both on the moving object and the target object?